# How to add video to my site?

Tags: video, video-streaming

I have a website, Now I need to add screen-casting (the movies are in ogg format) to that site.
All videos are less than 1MB in size.
I don't want to use third party players like youtube on my site.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking into the video tag, take note of the browser support:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html

Answer (score 2):

I like [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/), however, you would need to convert your OGG to something like FLV. The ffmpeg command line tool can do this quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Download [FREE STUDIO](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software.htm) and you'll find solution there with code example.

Bottom-left on **[this page](http://www.service-kl.com/)** you can see how it looks like.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please leave a comment when you downvote.

Comment: Because it's always easier to click DOWN-ARROW then to check out solution. Don't worry, I call that democracy :)

Comment: But he doesn't want to host on youtube

Comment: I know and that's it. FLV file, player and its XML configuration are on my server. YouTube doesn't have anything with this. I suggested FreeStudio because an option to create test-video HTML page, during conversion any_video->flv. There's great example how to embed own video files hosted at own server, to own webpage.